# array not working with ajax post

Tags: php, ajax, post

everything work good except my array. when i click few time on sent the `count($a)` stay at 1.
`$catbotreply` is the reply of my msg.

```
$a=array();
array_unshift($a,$catbotreply); 

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").on("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php",
                data: $("#catbot").serialize() + "&d=d",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#catbotResult').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>



 if (isset($_POST['msg'])) {





   $response.= ' <b class="yousay">You say:</b>' . stripslashes($usermessage) . '<br /><br />';
$response.= '<b class="catbotsays">Bot:</b>' . $catbotreply . '<br /><br />';
 $response.= count($a);              
echo $response;
}






     <form name="catbot" id="catbot" action="<?php echo($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">
                    <b>Msg:</b>
                    <input type="text" name="msg" size="30" class="text">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send!" class="bttn">
                    <input type="text" name="lastcatbot" value="<?php echo $simplecatbot; ?>">
                    <input type="text" name="lastwascomm" value="<?php echo $command; ?>">
                </form>

                <hr>
                <div class="leftalign" id="catbotResult">
                    <b class="yousay">You say:</b>Connected!<br /><br />
                    <b class="catbotsays">Bot:</b>Connected!<br /><br />
                </div>
```

before i add the ajax function i was using a hidden text to save my last msg and i understand if i use echo in the same page the data won't refresh so its why i added the `count($a)` to `$response`. my msg and bot reply refresh at every msg but my count stay at 1 . anyone know why?

Comment: Parse your data using `$.JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: what's in the `$a` ?

Comment: $a is my array, used for keeping my last msg

Comment: Where did you pushed value into `$a` ? @MartinDubois

Comment: with unshift, i tryed with push also but i prefer from beginning of my array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the way you are sending the data in ajax.

```
data: {catbot:$("#catbot").serialize() ,d:"d"},
```

And receive as

```
$_POST['catbot'];
$_POST['d'];
```

Comment: what's problem in `$("#catbot").serialize() + "&d=d"` as op ha catching only `msg` ?

Comment: data can be sent both object and name value pair